Factor Random Slope Models Showing Referece as Random Effects in Glmer Logit
I am running a logistic regression model with random slopes in R, where the variable m_edu varies between countries.
fsdisability1 ~ factor(caretakerdis) + (-1 + factor(caretakerdis) |      country)

The results are:
     AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 36948.69  36991.89 -18469.35  36938.69     41789 
Random effects:
 Groups  Name                  Std.Dev. Corr
 country factor(caretakerdis)0 0.4955       
         factor(caretakerdis)1 0.3712   0.95
Number of obs: 41794, groups:  country, 10
Fixed Effects:
          (Intercept)  factor(caretakerdis)1  
              -1.6185                 0.7259 

do not understand why factor(caretakerdis)0 (the reference level) is appearing as a random effect. Can anyone help explain why this is happening? Additionally, I have removed the intercept as a random effect, but the results still show factor(caretaker)0 as the intercept. What should I do to ensure that the random term for the reference variable is excluded, and Is factor(caretaker)0 appear here as an intercept?

You added random slopes for the effect of factor(caretakerdis) in the model and you also avoided a random intercept for countries. Thinking of a regression as y = b0 + x*b1, this means that b0 does not vary between countries, but b1 does. Given that you have a 2-category predictor, this may be a sensible method.
